# Mongodb: how to give multiple conditions?

Tags: mongodb

I need to check the status of my condition.I need to check both "completed" and "stopped" status.

So how do I give the condition here my query:

```
var query = { };
    query.status = { $ne: "Stopped" };
            query.status = { $ne: "Completed" };
```

I give condition like this means it will take either only one condition only. I need to check both conditions.

what can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use operator [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), for example:

```
var query = {$and:[{status:{ $ne: "Stopped" }}, {status:{ $ne: "Completed" }}] };
```

Comment: This works fine but I need to check more than that ex I in that query itself I want to check mail id and some object id.For that what can i do?

Comment: @Prakash just add other statements to the query:
`var query = {$and:[{status:{ $ne: "Stopped" }}, {status:{ $ne: "Completed" }}, {mail:"some@email.com"}, {_id:"id"}] };`